# Git confusion. "fatal: failed to open 'app/lang/en/homepage.php': File exists"

Tags: linux, git

The other day I had to have a full image restore of one of our production servers due to a problem encountered with git and not having any clue how to solve the issue. The standard workflow, which has worked for almost 2 years without a problem has been:

- Make local changes
- Commit
- Finish feature (GitFlow)
- Push to remote origin
- Login to server, go to http root and issue the following command:

  > git pull master Version_1.x.x

However, this time instead of this working as usual I was presented with this error.

```
fatal: failed to open 'app/lang/en/homepage.php': File exists
```

That file was updated in dev as were several other files. I immediately got server monitoring notification that the website was no longer responding. So I loaded it up and I got a 404 error??

Returning to the console I did `git status` and was blown away with what was shown.

```
On branch master
   Changed but not updated:
   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

modified:   app/views/layouts/landingBody.blade.php
modified:   app/views/layouts/trailblazers.blade.php
modified:   app/views/mobile/UI/landingBody.blade.php
modified:   public/images/spashPage_full_new.jpg

Untracked files:
   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

public/images/3rd_Party/
public/images/UI_bg_login_summer2015.jpg
public/images/spashPage_full_1024_summer2015.jpg
public/images/spashPage_full_1200_summer2015.jpg
public/images/spashPage_full_blur_summer2015.jpg
public/images/spashPage_full_summer2015.jpg

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

How is this possible that files have been changed in production and files that were part of the latest update were reporting as untracked files?

So I tried stashing the changes which predictably returned the following on the next `git status`

```
On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

I tried everything from reset hard to reset to a specific commit and it progressively got worse to the point I was getting.

I got errors such as

```
git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD
error: git checkout-index: unable to create file app/3rdParty/Mobile_Detect.php (File exists)
error: git checkout-index: unable to create file app/config/app.php (File exists)
```

Not knowing what else to do, I did a full restore from a snapshot. Now that I am back to the last backup, which was less than 16hrs old, and no other changes made since then I do a `git status` on the same production machine. Just to check before actually issuing another git pull command and messing everything up again. The following was result:

```
On branch master
Changed but not updated:
   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

modified:   public/.htaccess

Untracked files:
   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

app/config/auth.php
app/config/cache.php
app/config/compile.php
app/config/database.php
app/config/remote.php
app/config/session.php
app/views/emails/
app/views/hello.php
bootstrap/compiled.php
readme.md
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Again how is this possible? Nothing is ever done in production except `git pull <local branch> <origin branch>`, yet there are untracked files and modified files.

I have updates which need to be "pushed" into production but I can't have the website go down again. Not being a git expert makes this especially difficult.

I did check the git log on production and compared it with the origin, and dev and the commits all match up. This is all very perplexing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Qs/things to try:
* What does `git remote -v show` say?
* Does your Git repo have hooks that may be changing the code?
* What if you did a `git pull && git checkout <branch>` instead?
* What scripts are run out of cron on the server, if any?
* What if you took a clean test machine/VM and just did a checkout of the branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was within dropbox. The .gitignore file for one of the sub directories was removed and replaced with an alternate version and was unintentionally pushed in a previous release. The next time it was time to update everything was completely out of whack. Replacing the .gitignore file with the correct version and doing a hard reset, followed by a pull resolved the issue. Lesson: Dropbox can be dangerous when playing in the same sandbox as git.